# How to get a number higher than a given value

Tags: ruby

I'm  trying to write a function that receives a value, `val` and outputs the smallest higher number than the given value. This number belongs to a set of positive integers that have the following properties: Their digits occur only once, they are odd and they are multiple of three.

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
def next_numb(n)

  x = n + 3
  if x % 2 == 1 && x % 3 == 0
    return x
  end
end
```

How can I test for unique numbers?  Also, if I enter 12 the answer is 15 and the same is for 13.

Comment: Would `next_numb(15)` return `15` or `21`?

Comment: it will be `21`, since OP's looking for the next number.

Comment: I don't think I've seen that abbreviation for the word "number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if the number only has unique values, you can do this:

```
num.to_s.split('').uniq == num.to_s.split('')
```

You are splitting each number into its individual digits, as strings, and then running `uniq` to remove duplicates, and, if that is the same as the array without `uniq`, then you have a number with non-duplicate digits.

If you add this to your `if` statement, it will get pretty long, so I suggest you wrap this in a method that returns `true` or `false`:

```
def unique_digits?(num)
  num.to_s.split('').uniq == num.to_s.split('')
end
```

Your `if` statement will be:

```
def next_numb(n)
  x = n + 3
  if x % 2 == 1 && x % 3 == 0 && unique_digits?(x)
    return x
  end
end
```

I noticed something else about your code, it will only add 3 to `n` and checks if the number meets all of the conditions, if so, it will return the number, and if not, it will return `nil`.

If you have an input of `15`, your function will return `nil`, because `18` is not odd. The right number to return is `21`, so you will need a loop:

```
def next_numb(n)
  x = n + 1
  until x % 2 == 1 && x % 3 == 0 && unique_digits?(x)
    x += 1
  end
  x
end

def unique_digits?(num)
  num.to_s.split('').uniq == num.to_s.split('')
end

next_numb(13)  #=> 15
next_numb(15)  #=> 21
next_numb(125) #=> 129
```

Comment: so the method would read `def next_numb(n)

x = n + 3
 if x % 2 == 1 && x % 3 == 0 &&  x.to_s.split(//).uniq == x.to_s.split(//)
return x
 end
end`

Comment: yeah, but like i said, i would suggest putting that last part in a method, for readability.

Comment: `next_numb 125 #=> nil`

Comment: Thanks davidhu2000 . I will try that. Not sure if I need the `x = n + 3` . If I put 13 in the method it should return 15 like 12. So will need to try and work that out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe you can use `split` instead of `split('')` or even better use `chars`.

Comment: the default delimiter for `split` is white space, so you need the `('')` part, but `chars` will work

Comment: Please avoid using "edit" or "update" tags in your questions or answers. Instead, add the additional content where it would have been if it'd been there originally. We can see what changed if we need to.